# Parse xml - empty element

Tags: c#, xml

I have problem with parse XML, this is my xml:

```
<Invoice version="6.0.1">
   <DocumentType>1</DocumentType>
   <ID>FV17116113</ID>
   <InvoiceLines>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <UnitPrice>25</UnitPrice>
      </InvoiceLine>
      <InvoiceLine>
         <UnitPrice>55</UnitPrice>
      </InvoiceLine>
   </InvoiceLines>
</Invoice>
```

i try this code:

```
XmlDocument xml= new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(sourcexml);
foreach (XmlElement row in xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("InvoiceLines/InvoiceLine"))
{
}
```

But i have nothing in element row....
Have you any idea please?

Comment: Your code should work fine. Can you check what `sourcexml` is?

Comment: @HHLV - i load only one file *.isdoc...in this format is standart xml...

Comment: [seems to work fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W6nXWa) - please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It actually works. If you are looking for the value, try with the InnerText property as said. Also, i think the Load method expect a string with the FileName. You should change it to the LoadXml method.

Comment: Is `sourcexml` a string containing XML, or is it the path to an XML file on your disk?

Comment: its path to file on my disk...If i try xml.InnerText it a have data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually cannot understand your problem?
I guess you should remove xmlns attribute from your Invoice node.

Remove this

```
xmlns="http://isdoc.cz/namespace/2013"
```

Then, your code will work

```
  foreach (XmlElement row in xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("InvoiceLines/InvoiceLine"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row.InnerText);
            }
```

Comment: I don't belive so. I can see 25 and 55 in my output window.

Comment: it is any online page, where can i upload structure my file and you test it?

Comment: Yes, format is correct...i try this...Is is possible to copy my file to web and you check on this?